# Userinterface with multiple inputfields

Tags: c, user-interface, user-input

I need to develop a userinterface for a financial calculator that I recently developed in c. A window with multiple inputfields and a field where the calculated value is displayed

I got this link from my teacher (gtk) but cannot find any example of it

https://developer.gnome.org/gtk-tutorial/2.22/c39.html

shortly - I need to know how to develop a userinterface with multiple inputfields in c. If I could not find it in this gtk-tutorial -where could I find it?

Thanks in advance for any sugesstions!!!

Comment: Is there a question here? The link you provided *is* a tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

you should try this tutorial: http://zetcode.com/gui/gtksharp/

You can also have a look at the Qt Framework which is also very nice and a little
more easy to use http://qt-project.org/resources/getting_started